# SQL Query sorting data from one field into two result fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I see several things similar to what I need to do but not quite and just don't have enough info to make this work yet.

Table has three fields (GroupID, ParentID and Name).  ParentID, for the Child GroupID, contains the related GroupID of the Parent.  The Parent then has a different row in the table then the Child.  The name of the Parent or Child falls in the Name field.

I want the result to give me columns of ChildName and ParentName as further filtered by only grabbing certain Parent's Children from the table.

To state this another way, I want the ChildName and related ParentName for all children related to certain ParentIDs in the table.

How can I query against this single table to get these results.

================================================================================

OK 1st post Newbie here in case that is not obvious.  Thanks for the assist.

This is SQL as stated in the topic title and the tag.  Next time I will also include in body.  More precisely it is SQL Server 2014.

An example of the data I am manipulating (source) is:

====================================

## | GroupId | ParentId | Name        |

### | 701     | 818      | Item A      |

### | 703     | 818      | Item C      |

### | 704     | 818      | Item D      |

## | 818     | 0        | Container A |

and what I want to end up with (target) is:

=============================================

## | GroupId | ParentId | Item   | Container   |

### | 701     | 818      | Item A | Container A |

### | 703     | 818      | Item C | Container A |

## | 704     | 818      | Item D | Container A |

The actual table contains many Containers and I to narrow to just some of those containers.  Thinking that part would be a WHERE statement (ie: WHERE GroupId = 818 OR GroupId = 743 ...etc.) tacked onto what I learn here.  But there may be a better way.

THANKS

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Google "Recursive sql query"

Comment: Firstly, what have you tried so far???  Secondly, no one is able to help you if you don't tell which dbms you are using.  The syntax are different from one dbms to another.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: `no one is able to help you if you don't tell which dbms you are using` this is true because in some databases "recursive common table expressions" can be used, but in some others they cannot and in Oracle there are other features for hierarchies. *please also indicate version of your database*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the DBMS is mysql and you don't mind a rather huge dataset as this can end up huge if the GroupID is not distinct. (Every child times number of groupIDs that it's parent has

`select t1.*, t2.Name as parentName from theTable as t1 JOIN theTable as t2 ON (t1.parentID = t2.GroupID) WHERE t1.parentId in (1,2,3)`

Comment: Actually...  This was what I was looking for.  Thanks @Cemal.